# Set one element width equal to another

Tags: javascript

I'd like to set the div width equal to the image width. Here's what I can think of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function ()
{
document.getElementById('foo').style.width = document.getElementById('bar').width + 'px';
}
</script>
<div id="foo" style="background:red;"><img id="bar" src="image.jpg"></div>
```

It seems to be working, but I'm not sure if it's correct coding.

Thanks in advance for checking the code or any improvement you suggest!

Rain lover

Comment: Won't your div auto-expand to accommodate the image?

Comment: The div width value is always larger than image width as it's a block element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to specify a width for the div. You can give the parent div a float value.

http://jsfiddle.net/46JTb/

But if you want it to truly be the same value, I believe your method will suffice.

Comment: Using float was the right way to do it -- simple and clever! Thanks! :)